# System.NullReferenceException with F# and iOS on Xamarin

Tags: ios, f#, xamarin

I have a very strange error when executing some test code testing a different module that is hosted in a standalone project but within the same solution within Xamarin Studio.

The solution hosts 2 projects. A module-project and a test-project. The test-project references the module-project via a project-reference.

```
//module-project/FluidLayout.fs
namespace iosautolayout
open System

 module Fluidity =
     type Init<'a> = Init of 'a
     type Right<'a> = Right of 'a
     type Left<'a> = Left of 'a

     type HorizontalBuilder() =
         member x.Yield(()) = Init "Init"
         [<CustomOperation("part")>]
         member x.Part(Init v, a) = Left "Left"

     let horizontal = new HorizontalBuilder()

      let create () = 
          let test_h = horizontal {
              part "test"
          }
          test_h
```

Then I have the test project with 2 files in it
    //test-project/Tests.fs
    namespace ioslibrarytests

```
open System
open NUnit.Framework;
open iosautolayout.Fluidity
open MonoTouch.UIKit
open MonoTouch.Foundation

#nowarn "0025"

[<TestFixture>]
type Tests() =

    [<Test>]
    member me.``Create Structure with DSL``() =
        let z = create ()
        ()
```

And the AppDelegate to start everything

```
//test-project/AppDelegate.fs
namespace ioslibrarytests

open System
open MonoTouch.UIKit
open MonoTouch.Foundation
open MonoTouch.NUnit.UI

[<Register("AppDelegate")>]
type AppDelegate() = 
    inherit UIApplicationDelegate()
    override val Window = null with get, set
    override this.FinishedLaunching(app, options) = 
        this.Window <- new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds)
        let runner = new TouchRunner(this.Window)
        runner.Add (System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ());
        this.Window.RootViewController <- new UINavigationController (runner.GetViewController ());
        this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible()
        true

module Main = 
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main args = 
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate")
        0
```

This gives me the following error

```
 2015-02-15 15:11:46.902 ioslibrarytests[1017:14804]    
 [FAIL] Create Structure with DSL : System.NullReferenceException : 
        Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 2015-02-15 15:11:46.902 ioslibrarytests[1017:14804] at
 iosautolayout.Fluidity.create () [0x00000] in 
 /Users/projekte/pawo-pic/ios-autolayout/FluidLayout.fs:17 
 2015-02-15 15:11:46.902 ioslibrarytests[1017:14804] at
 ioslibrarytests.Tests.Create Structure with DSL () [0x00000] in 
 /Users/projekte/pawo-pic/ios-library-tests/Tests.fs:17 
 2015-02-15 15:11:46.902 ioslibrarytests[1017:14804] at 
 (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke 
 (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
 2015-02-15 15:11:46.902 ioslibrarytests[1017:14804] at 
 System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags 
 invokeAttr,   System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, 
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00044] in 
 /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:230 201
```

I am completely lost to what happens here.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - But now I am even more confused.

If I change `horizontal` to a function instead of a val all works fine

```
namespace iosautolayout
open System

module Fluidity =
    type Init<'a> = Init of 'a
    type Right<'a> = Right of 'a
    type Left<'a> = Left of 'a

    type HorizontalBuilder() =
        member x.Yield(()) = Init "Init"
        [<CustomOperation("part")>]
        member x.Part(Init v, a) = Left "Left"

    let horizontal () = new HorizontalBuilder()
    let create () = 
        let test_h = horizontal() {
            part "test"
        }
        test_h
```

In the interactive Window it doesnt matter if I use horizontal as value or as a function.

Can anybody shed some light on this behavior?